# Cannot get jquery data() of parent's parent. Only returns undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

list:

```
<ul class="div_chart1" data-quickcode="mac" data-questionid="1" >
    <li>
       <img src="inmark/pie_icon.jpg" class="pie_icon" onclick="ok()"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

function:

```
function ok(){          
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().data('quickcode'));
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().data('questionid'));  
}
```

function ok() returns undefined. What is wrong with this?

Comment: pass the element object. `this` is referring here to window object currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to pass the `this` reference as an argument to the inline handler,

HTML:

```
<img src="inmark/pie_icon.jpg" class="pie_icon" onclick="ok(this)"/>
```

JS:

```
function ok(elem){          
    console.log($(elem).closest('ul').data('quickcode'));
    console.log($(elem).closest('ul').data('questionid'));  
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/SRxYP/)

---

And the best way of doing this would be,

```
$('.pie_icon').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var parent = $(this).closest('ul');
  console.log(parent.data('quickcode'));
  console.log(parent.data('questionid'));  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your context is referring to global window object.

```
console.log(this); // Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

So pass element object like,

```
<img src="inmark/pie_icon.jpg" class="pie_icon" onclick="ok(this)"/>  


function ok(element) {
    console.log($(element).parent().parent().data('quickcode'));
    console.log($(element).parent().parent().data('questionid'));
} // here is element is HTML element object. Just wrap it with jQuery to use jQuery function.
```

### [More about inline event handlers](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/)